# Is this the correct way to show data in React from a fetch request, if not how do I change JSX being rendered to a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am new to using React and I'm not sure what's the best practice or correct way I should be displaying data.

Should I always be looking to break down things that can be potentially their own component into smaller components, rather than having one big  component render? I am assuming yes. I just don't know when.

Anyways, I have the following component which makes a fetch request to an api. It returns some data. I set the state to the data. Then I create a variable coins, which maps data into a `<ul>` with `<li>`. I then return it as a `<div>` containing the data as `{coins}`. My question is, should the `<ul>` and the `<li>` be created as a separate component, which takes props, which will be the state of the this Coins' component? Can someone help me get started?

```
export default class Coins extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            lists: [],
            error: null,
        };
    }
    //lifecycle method to call loadCoins when Coins component is displayed?
    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadCoins();
    }

    //Data fetch from Coins API
    loadCoins() {
        this.setState({
            error: null,
            loading: true
        });
        return fetch(API_BASE_URL)
        .then(res => {
            if(!res.ok) {
                return Promise.reject(res.statusText);
            }
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(coins => {
            console.log('coins:', coins);
            this.setState({
                lists: coins.Data,
                loading: false
            })
        }
        )
        .catch(err => {
            this.setState({
                error: 'Could not load coins',
                loading: false
            })
        });
    }

    //Map the fetch data into individual cards/uls as JSX
    render() {
        const coins = this.state.lists.map((coin, index) => {
            return <ul className='coin-containers' key={coin.CoinInfo.Id}>
            <li><img className='coinImages' src={`${API_BASE_IMAGE}${coin.CoinInfo.ImageUrl}`} alt={coin.CoinInfo.FullName}/></li>
            <li>{index+1}</li>
            <li>{coin.CoinInfo.FullName}</li>
            <li className='ticker'>{coin.CoinInfo.Name}</li>
            <li>{coin.DISPLAY.USD.PRICE}</li>
            <li>{coin.DISPLAY.USD.SUPPLY}</li>
            <li>{coin.DISPLAY.USD.MKTCAP}</li>
            <li>24HR</li>
            <li>{coin.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEPCT24HOUR}%</li>
            </ul>
        });

        //display the new array of mapped coins data
        return (
        <div className='purse'>
            {coins}  
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya I would make a component (or a function if that seems more appropriate) to render an individual coin.

You could make a `<Coin>` component and pass the needed data to it as props:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className='purse'>
      {this.state.lists.map((coin, index) => <Coin data={coin} index={index} key={coin.CoinInfo.Id} />)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or just move the rendering of a coin to a new function:

```
renderCoin(coin, index) {
  return <ul className='coin-containers' key={coin.CoinInfo.Id}>
    <li><img className='coinImages' src={`${API_BASE_IMAGE}${coin.CoinInfo.ImageUrl}`} alt={coin.CoinInfo.FullName}/>
    </li>
    <li>{index + 1}</li>
    <li>{coin.CoinInfo.FullName}</li>
    <li className='ticker'>{coin.CoinInfo.Name}</li>
    <li>{coin.DISPLAY.USD.PRICE}</li>
    <li>{coin.DISPLAY.USD.SUPPLY}</li>
    <li>{coin.DISPLAY.USD.MKTCAP}</li>
    <li>24HR</li>
    <li>{coin.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEPCT24HOUR}%</li>
  </ul>;
}
render() {
  return (
    <div className='purse'>
      {this.state.lists.map((coin, index) => this.renderCoin(coin, index))}
    </div>
  );
}
```